# How to clip texture in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, texture2d

I need to crop the image. But in opencv, it will create error because of integer domain. So I want to crop every single unit in float domain to reduce the offset error. Maybe openGL can help me, but I'm not good at it.

The image just like this ( but not this one ):

[image: The image just like this]

I want every black and white unit, then save them in cv::Mat.

I guess maybe shader or loop or something else can repeat to crop all block, then save them.

Now I can get one single unit. Like this:

```
glfwInit();//initalization
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);

GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(100, 100, "LearnOpenGL", nullptr, nullptr);
if (window == nullptr)
{
    cout << "Failed to create GLFW window" << endl;
    glfwTerminate();
    return false;
}
glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress))
{
    std::cout << "Failed to initialize GLAD" << std::endl;
    return false;
}

Shader ourShader("vertex.vs.glsl", "fragment.fs.glsl");

float unitWidth = moduleLength / (float)tex.cols;
float startP_x = 100.0f / (float)tex.cols + unitWidth * 2;
float startP_y = 104.0f / (float)tex.rows + unitWidth * 2;
float vertices[] = {
    // positions        // texture coords (note that we changed them to 'zoom in' on our texture image)
     0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,     startP_x + unitWidth,   startP_y, // top right
     0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,     startP_x + unitWidth,   startP_y + unitWidth, // bottom right
    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,     startP_x,               startP_y + unitWidth, // bottom left
    -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,     startP_x,               startP_y  // top left 
};

unsigned int indices[] = {
   0, 1, 3, // first triangle
   1, 2, 3  // second triangle
};

unsigned int VBO, VAO, EBO;

glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
glGenBuffers(1, &EBO);

glBindVertexArray(VAO);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

// position attribute
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
// texture coord attribute
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(float), (void*)(3 * sizeof(float)));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);


// texture 
// ---------
GLuint texture;
glGenTextures(1, &texture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
//// set the texture wrapping parameters
// set the texture wrapping parameters
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);  
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);
// set texture filtering parameters
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

GLubyte* pixels;
int width = tex.cols;
int height = tex.rows;

int pixellength = width * height*tex.channels();
pixels = new GLubyte[pixellength];
memcpy(pixels, tex.data, pixellength * sizeof(unsigned char));
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
free(pixels);

while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
{
    glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    // bind Texture
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

    // draw our first triangle
    ourShader.use();

    // create transformations
    glm::mat4 model = glm::mat4(1.0f); // make sure to initialize matrix to identity matrix first
    glm::mat4 view = glm::mat4(1.0f);
    glm::mat4 projection = glm::mat4(1.0f);

    model = glm::rotate(model, glm::radians(0.0f), glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
    view = glm::translate(view, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.1f));
    projection = glm::perspective(glm::radians(45.0f), (float)SCR_WIDTH / (float)SCR_HEIGHT, 0.1f, 100.0f);

    // retrieve the matrix uniform locations
    unsigned int modelLoc = glGetUniformLocation(ourShader.ID, "model");
    unsigned int viewLoc = glGetUniformLocation(ourShader.ID, "view");
    unsigned int transformLoc = glGetUniformLocation(ourShader.ID, "projection");

    glUniformMatrix4fv(modelLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(model));
    glUniformMatrix4fv(viewLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, &view[0][0]);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(transformLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(projection));

    glBindVertexArray(VAO); // seeing as we only have a single VAO there's no need to bind it every time, but we'll do so to keep things a bit more organized
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0); // set the count to 6 since we're drawing 6 vertices now (2 triangles); not 3!

    glfwPollEvents();
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
}

glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
glDeleteBuffers(1, &VBO);
glDeleteBuffers(1, &EBO);

glfwTerminate();
return true;
```

vetex shader:

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 aTexCoord;

uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;

out vec2 TexCoord;

void main()
{
    gl_Position =  projection * view * model *vec4(aPos, 1.0);
    TexCoord = vec2(aTexCoord.x, aTexCoord.y);
}
```

fragment shader:

```
#version 330 core
out vec4 FragColor;

in vec2 TexCoord;

uniform sampler2D texture1;


void main()
{
    FragColor = texture(texture1, TexCoord);
}
```

Comment: Doing a round-trip to the GPU  to crop an image doesn't make the slightest sense, if have to transfer the input data and the cropped parts back, which will be more expensive than just cropping it directly. No idea waht you tried in OpenCV, but image cropping can be done there.

Comment: Your probelm isn't even ewll-specified. You can't crop "sub-pixels". You might want some weird sub-pixel level scaling, but that in unclear and would not make  a lot of sense. Also, the error would not accumulate? Why would it? You always get an error <= 0.5 pixels for each single part.

Comment: @derhass Cause I want to reduce the error first. For example, in integer domain, if the cropping start point is (0,0), range is 1.9 pixel. Then after 10 blocks, it will accumulate 1 pixel offset in cropping, which means blocks after that will have a wrong cropping start point. So I can’t have the “correct unit” with totally black or white. It will be the “mixed block” that is not what I need.

Comment: @derhass Of course can’t crop “sub-pixels”. Just want to try if this case in float domain, the performance will be better or worse. In other words, OpenGL helps calculate the float domain. I am wondering whether this way can work or not.

Comment: "For example, in integer domain, if the cropping start point is (0,0), range is 1.9 pixel. Then after 10 blocks, it will accumulate 1 pixel offset in cropping,". No, it wouldn't. `round(1.9*10)` yields 19. What you seem to suggest is something like `10*round(1.9)` which doesn't make the slightest sense. And OpenGL can't change any of that, and is totally useless for your use-case.